# Is Poco RefCountedObject thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco, poco-libraries

Poco RefCountedObject offer 2 interfaces:

```
    inline void RefCountedObject::duplicate() const
{
    ++_counter;
}


inline void RefCountedObject::release() const throw()
{
    try
    {
        if (--_counter == 0) delete this;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        poco_unexpected();
    }
}
```

With:

```
class Foundation_API RefCountedObject
    /// A base class for objects that employ
    /// reference counting based garbage collection.
    ///
    /// Reference-counted objects inhibit construction
    /// by copying and assignment.
{
public:
    RefCountedObject();
        /// Creates the RefCountedObject.
        /// The initial reference count is one.

    void duplicate() const;
        /// Increments the object's reference count.

    void release() const throw();
        /// Decrements the object's reference count
        /// and deletes the object if the count
        /// reaches zero.

    int referenceCount() const;
        /// Returns the reference count.

protected:
    virtual ~RefCountedObject();
        /// Destroys the RefCountedObject.

private:
    RefCountedObject(const RefCountedObject&);
    RefCountedObject& operator = (const RefCountedObject&);

    mutable AtomicCounter _counter;
};
```

Note that:
**mutable AtomicCounter _counter;**

my question is if I use a RefCountedObject in multithreading is it safe?

In my opinion it's not because only --_counter is atomic but if(--_count) is not atomic and could lead to having a reference to a deleted object.
For example let say I have 2 threads A and B one executing duplicate and the other release, the execution sequence is as follow:

- B start executing release and reach --_counter
- A start executing duplicate and reach ++_counter
- At this point _counter=1
- B execute --_counter and return the result to be evaluated by the if (which is 0 && counter is 0 now)
- B is preempted and stop before the branching statement (the if)
- A execute _counter++ and return a reference to the object
- B continue and evaluate the branching statement with value 0 and delete the object

We end up with A having a reference to a deleted object.
even if the mutable keyword force the compiler to not optimize the _counter it won't help in multithreading

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly from looking at duplicate and release in isolation, the above is correct.

However, if you have two threads, both having a pointer to the same RefCountedObject, you either should have separate AutoPtr instances in each thread (which implies the _counter is > 1 to begin with), or, if you share the same AutoPtr, it must be protected by a mutex, if at least one thread can change the AutoPtr (which would result in release() being called). Needless to say sharing an mutable AutoPtr between multiple threads is a recipe for disaster.

If you manage RefCountedObject by manually calling duplicate() and release() (which I would not recommend), you should follow POCO's reference counting rules and be very careful.

So, for well-behaved code, RefCountedObject together with AutoPtr is safe for multithreaded use.

Comment: you say "separate AutoPtr instances in the 2 threads". How that work? if we have 2 separate instances we will have two separate refCount so how will we be able to delete the object at the right time?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe because the counter is based on `std::atomic` **AND** `std::atomic` is using by default `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for its operation.
If `std::atomic` was using `std::memory_order_relaxed`, then the implementation would be buggy/unsafe.
The downside, is that `std::memory_order_seq_cst` is "slow". There are faster implementations than Poco's, but less simple, by using some different code and different memory ordering commands (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)